# How can you keep the "theme" of your website and add new dynamic pages?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I'm starting to learn programming, and have pretty much grasped HTML, CSS and JavaScript, now looking to actually pick up a back-end language.

One thing that was never explained is how to update/add content to a webpage without going back to the source code/copying and pasting the html and editing the body.

Also, I would like a brief explanation as to how I can implement a system where users can generate pages. Kickstarter would be a good example, such as how users can make campaigns and have a dedicated page for their campaigns.

Comment: You need to pick up a serverside language (PHP, Node.js, Java, .NET) and learn about databases.

Comment: PHP would be a good route if you plan to host it on a cheaper server (PHP is installed on most hosts' servers). If you don't mind paying a *little* more for a server you have root access to, go the node.js route (or [io.js](https://iojs.org/) which is a fork of node.js that has a lot of momentum right now). node/io.js has the benefit of being JavaScript, so you should feel right at home.

Comment: But Rails (Ruby) is an awesome option. You can use Heroku for free to host it. Check out Rails for Zombies to start learning (don't need to download anything) http://railsforzombies.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is exactly why a server side language is needed. The server generates html pages for you on the fly using an html template you provide and data from the database or other sources. I suggest you pick up a server side language and you'll understand. For the kickstarter thing you need Authorizations, session and many more, that topic is too big to be discussed in a stackoverflow answer.

Comment: Thank you! Where would I be able to access these generated pages? I'm looking at learning either Ruby on Rails or PHP. Where would this database be?

Comment: The generated pages get delivered to the client's browser. If you want to edit them you'll need to have access to the orginal html file. The database is a software that stores all your data (account names, passwords, campaigns, etc). I think it's better if you start with PHP, I think it's easier to begin with. Once you're good with it I would move to something else. The best advice I can give now is "Go buy a book about php, or do some tutorials online. It will be boring at first but you'll get to the fun part pretty quickly"

Answer (score 0):

This topic is very big, you need to start learning some web technology for it. I would say like asp.net or php. Then you will have to develop a custom CMS, which stands for Content Management System. From CMS pages can be added, deleted and updated. You will need a database like Sql server for storing the page data like page title, description, images etc. The best i could say it will take few months to take to in a situation where you can develop your own CMS. If you ask me the best approach for it, i would say get a Wrox book on Asp.net, C# and Sql Server and start your first step from today itself. 
Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely learn to program backend languages as others have suggested, and develop your own custom CMS.  That said, if you are mostly a front-end developer (working graphics, javascript, and the like) you may just want to learn to utilize one of the many free CMSs out there.  DotNetNuke (DNN) is based on .NET. Drupal or Joomla are also decent products, if you want to go with a PHP based solution. Alot of these already have pre-defined modules you can add in to give you a lot of backend functionality without much programming. Its pretty easy to learn how to create a skin or template to convert your HTML/css design for use with these systems.  As you want more custom functionality you can create your own custom modules by building them through PHP or .NET.

Comment: Could a site like kickstarter be made with Drupal or Joomla?

Comment: I've got more experinence with Drupal, and so I know you could definitely do something like Kickstart with it. Pretty sure Joomla can do the same.

Answer (score 0):

Everyone is talking more about the dynamic side of your question while I'd like to also mention the theme portion.

## Theme

It's common for websites to use the same css files across multiple pages. So you'll often see a style.css or application.css that contains more broad styles for elements and specific styles for classes. I often even make a theme.css to keep track of styling for links, headers, etc. and then still have css files for each individual page if it needs it.

What makes it even easier, is using something like [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) or LESS, where you can use variables, nesting, and mixins.

## Dynamic

On the dynamic side of your question, I'd like to recommend using Ruby on Rails. Ruby is a very easy language to learn, plus the community for Rails is wonderful. There are many websites that assist in teaching you both Ruby and Rails such as [Try Ruby](http://tryruby.org/) or [Rails for Zombies](http://railsforzombies.org). Both are free and are completely online so you don't even need to download Ruby to get started.

An example of what you'd have to do to make project pages like kickstarter is very simple. You would have a route that directs part of the url into a variable

```
GET "/projects/:name", to: "projects#show"
```

And then you would have a controller that would handle taking the request and its parameters and getting the data you would want to show. So you can just move the `:name` of the URL into a variable if you want

```
@name = params[:name]
```

And then you have a view for the page, where you can write plain HTML, but when you want to embed something dynamic, you write embedded Ruby (stuff between the `<%= %>`).

```
<h3><%= @name %></h3>
<div>This is a project</h3>
```

To display more data than just what's given to you in the URL you would probably want to work with a database. With Rails that's very simple because the database calls are wrapped in Ruby so you can do things like having a create Project page and then in the controller you can do `Project.create(name: params[:name])`.